# RewriteCond for multiple files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

In htaccess file, RewriteCond  for one file `bla.php` can write so right?

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !bla.php
```

Question: how can write RewriteCond  for multiple files? for example for 3 files: `bla.php`, `bla1.php`, `bla2.php`
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regular expressions:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !bla[0-9]*\.php
```

If it is only a limited number of files you can simply directly cite the names:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(asd|dh6|some_some)\.php
```

though it is more elegant to use separate conditions and combine them:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !asd\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !dh6\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !some_some\.php
```

Comment: Tell please how will be writed, if needed RewriteCond  for 3 files: `asd.php`,`dh6.php`,`some_some.php`, and RewriteCond  needed only this files, not other files.

Comment: You can't figure that out yourself?

Comment: Thanks very much, and one question, if I write this `[AND]`, not works, if I write without `[AND]` works. what means `[AND]` in your code?

Comment: Sorry, my fault, I removed it. The three conditions have to be logically combined in an 'and' fashion: all three conditions have to be true, not just a single one. Since the 'and' combination is the default it does not have to be specified. You might want to read about the `[OR]` flag for `RewriteCond` in the manual, in case you need it one day.